# KeysOnly Function dont return Keys

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I experiment a little bit with `GAE`, but now I have a problem. First of all I store some stuff into the `datastore`, with an `NewIncompleteKey`.
So there is the issue. My Website sends timestamps (I handle them as "ID"s) to the back-end. I parse then and want to delete them from the `datastore`. 
I thought I can do this.

```
type Food struct{
    Id int64
    Course string
    Name string 
    Date string
    Price float64
}

...Some Code...

func deleteEntries(mealsID []string, r *http.Request) int{
    // Get context from 
    c := appengine.NewContext(r);


    for _,id := range mealsID{
        var key *datastore.Key = nil
        q := datastore.NewQuery("Meal").Ancestor(mealStoreKey(c)).Filter("Course =", "dessert").KeysOnly()
        _, err := q.GetAll(c, key)
        if err != nil{
            return 0
        }
        log.Printf("Here the keys: %T %v ", key, key)
        log.Printf("%v ", id)
        e := datastore.Delete(c, key)
        if e != nil{
            return 33       
        }       
    }

    return len(mealsID)
}
```

But it doesn't work, because I get an error at the `datastore.Delete()` function. Anyone an idea?

**Edit:**

Part I:

```
   keys, err := q.GetAll(c, nil)
   …
   err = datastore.DeleteMulti(c, keys)
```

**Thanks to Dave.**

Part II:

I passed an String as Filter vaule to the query, but it have to be an Int64 same as in the datastore. Note to my self: *You have to pass also the same type of var to the query.*

```
func deleteEntries(mealsID []string, r *http.Request) int{
 // Get context from 
 c := appengine.NewContext(r);


 for _,id := range mealsID{
     ID,_ := strconv.Atoi(id)
     q:= datastore.NewQuery("Meal").Ancestor(mealStoreKey(c)).Filter("Id =", ID ).KeysOnly()
     keys, err := q.GetAll(c, nil)
     if err != nil{
         return 0
     }
     log.Printf("ID: %v ", id)
     log.Printf("Keys: %v ", keys)
     e := datastore.DeleteMulti(c, keys)
     if e != nil{
         log.Printf("%v ", e)
             return 0       
     }      
 }

 return len(mealsID)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keys are returned from `GetAll`. So you should instead write:

```
keys, err := q.GetAll(c, nil)
…
err = datastore.DeleteMulti(c, keys)
```

`GetAll` ignores the `dst` parameter for keys-only requests – [datastore reference](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Query.GetAll). So, in the example above, `key` will still be set to `nil` which explains the error.

Comment: Thanks Dave, this was a part of the issue. I edit the solution to my post.